# CoreAnimatedPages hero-p attribute

Tags: polymer

While I was exploring `core-animated-pages` [examples](https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-animated-pages/demos/music.html), I have noticed `hero-p` attribute in some elements.

I cannot find any mention in the [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-animated-pages) about it.

What does this `hero-p` attribute exactly do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the hero transition runs, elements with the hero-p attribute get the following rules applied (see core-animated-pages/transitions/hero-transition.html):

```
  polyfill-next-selector { content: ':host > * [hero-p]'; }
  ::content > * /deep/ [hero-p] {
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 100ms ease-out;
    transition: box-shadow 100ms ease-out;
  }

  polyfill-next-selector { content: ':host > [animate] [hero-p]'; }
  ::content > [animate] /deep/ [hero-p] {
    box-shadow: none !important;
  }
```

Which removes any box-shadow they have applied when the transition runs.